# odd number list for Hash (SyntaxError), though I am using Ruby 1.8.7 hash declaration

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am trying to connect to Oracle database using 'activerecord' and Ruby 1.8.7 and getting below error on my Windows 7 machine. I searched around for this issue and came across 1.8 and 1.9 ruby declaration of 'Hash' however I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and I feel I am using correct hash declaration, please correct me if I am wrong.

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require':                       C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhancedadapter-1.5.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:917: odd number list for Hash (SyntaxError)
      read_committed:   "READ COMMITTED",
                     ^
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.5.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:917: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
      read_committed:   "READ COMMITTED",
                     ^
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.5.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:917: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.5.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:919: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.5.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:1471: dynamic constant assignment
  DBMS_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10000  # can be 1-1000000
                           ^
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.5.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:1555: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `establish_connection'
from oracle_conn_testing.rb:5
```

This is how my code looks like

```
require 'rubygems'
gem "activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter"
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "oracle_enhanced",
    :database => "someurl.net:1523/ABCAD",
    :username => "testing1",
    :password => "testing1")

class TestTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "TABLE_NAME"
  set_primary_key "ID"
end

TestTable.find(:all).each do |tt|
  p tt
end

nac = TestTable.new()
```

***Additional Information:***
I have below gems on my machine :
* LOCAL GEMS *

- actionmailer (2.3.4)
- actionpack (2.3.4)
- activerecord (2.3.4)
- activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.5.3)
- activeresource (2.3.4)
- activesupport (2.3.4)
- json (1.8.1)
- mysql (2.9.1 x86-mingw32)
- rack (1.0.1)
- rails (2.3.4)
- rake (10.1.1)
- ruby-oci8 (2.1.7 x86-mingw32)
- rubygems-update (1.4.2)

I use below ***Rubygems version***:

C:\Users\tester1>gem -v

1.4.2

I tried to connect using ***OCI8*** and I was able to get response out of Oracle database so there is no connectivity issue from my machine.

```
irb(main):006:0> OCI8.new('testing1', 'testing1', 'someurl.net:1523/ABCAD').exec('select sysdate from dual') do |r| puts r.join(', ') end
Mon Mar 10 15:09:23 -0400 2014
=> 1
```

I used below link as my reference:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/rubyhol/instructions/rubyrails.htm

Comment: It looks like `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` latest version is not compatible with Ruby 1.8.7 due to hash syntax used in its source code. You could try an older version. You could also submit a request to fix it. If you have time you could have a try to fix it yourself and submit a pull request, but worth checking there is not any resistance to the idea. Ruby 1.8.7 is officially "not supported" to various degrees depending on the project.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I used 1.4.1 version of activerecord-oracle_enhancedadapter gem and it's working fine now Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message shows that your error is coming from inside the activerecord-oracle_enhancedadapter gem, and that gem has a Ruby 1.9 style hash.  You might find an older version of that gem that supports Ruby 1.8 and switch to that version.

Comment: Thanks David, I used 1.4.1 version of activerecord-oracle_enhancedadapter gem and it's working fine now Thanks a ton!